# Using already setup web scraper with Airflow?

Tags: web-scraping, airflow

the company I'm currently interning for wants me to schedule there already existing web scraper on to Airflow. I have 0 experience with webscrapers and airflow, however, I am writing to ask for some help.

First of all, the webscraper uses celery, selenium and rabbitMQ and is working perfectly fine without airflow. Now, my question is, to move this process onto airflow, is all I need to do is to import the functions into the airflow DAG that I wish to create and call them in the respective order that we want to them to be called in? Or is this a very simplistic view of things? Are there any things I need to keep in mind? I have been trying to read up on airflow for the past week, however, I cannot seem to make that break into scaling it to fit the company's code.

Apologies for the complete noob question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it already working as a script, all you have to do is to import the function that runs the entire code into a DAG and schedule it as per the interval you want.